# Detect scroll to bottom in an iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll

I'm using the following event to detect if the bottom of a page is reached when scrolling :

```
     $(window).scroll(function() {  
       if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()-$(window).height())
         alert('Bottom reached');    
       }
     });
```

This works fine on a normal page, but now I want this to work on a page that is ***inside an iframe***. This event must be declared inside the page in the iframe.
But `window` points to the page that contains the iframe, so I can't use that.

Any ideas?

Comment: `This event must be declared inside the page in the iframe. But window points to the page that contains the iframe` It shouldn't be the case. Can you replicate your issue?

Comment: Works as expected here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7bxq54zd/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your effort. It seems I did something wrong then in my page. Somehow I managed to get it working by using  $(document).scrollTop() though!