# Detect scrolling to bottom of a partial view in an MVC 5 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Partial view that returns a large amount of data in an HTML table. I've implemented the infinite scrolling technique using jquery [here](https://ricardodsanchez.com/2012/04/02/infinite-scroll-with-asp-net-mvc/) to load the table as you scroll down. Everything works as expected when I rendered the partial view from a view. but the scrolling is on the page level. I want to have the scroll bar only around the partial view table.
The problem is when I put a  tag around the partial view to set a scroll, it doesn't detect when the scroll hits the bottom.

I saw an implementation for this for iframe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703178/detect-scroll-to-bottom-in-an-iframe) but I need it for a partial view.

The view has only table headings and some text and then it calls the partial view below.

```
<div style="height: 400px; width: 600px; overflow: auto;">
        <div id="loading"></div>   
        <div id="productList">            
                @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName")            
        </div>  
</div>
```

These are the javascripts. How do I set the .scroll function to detect scrolling in the partial view?

```
function loadProducts() {
        if (page > -1 && !_inCallback) {
            _inCallback = true;
            page++;
            $('div#loading').html('<p><img src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif"></p>');
            $.get("/Users/Index/" + page, function (data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    $("#productList").append(data);
                }
                else {
                    page = -1;
                }

                _inCallback = false;
                $('div#loading').empty();
            });
        }
    }


    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            loadProducts();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your handling the `window` scroll event, but you need to handle the scroll event of the element in your partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you need a change in your scroll function. Have you tried change 'window' with '#productList'? 
I can't try it now, sorry, it's only an idea.

Edited: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/v2RbN/1/) is an example I've found in jsfiddle. Hope this will help you.

```
$(".box").scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        $("span").show();    
    } else {
        $("span").hide();
    }
});
```

Edited 2: I've found my answer was not correct: You're trying to capture scroll in the window. You need to capture the scroll in the div with overflow:auto...

html

```
<div id="overflowdiv" style="height: 400px; width: 600px; overflow: auto;">
        <div id="loading"></div>   
        <div id="productList">
```

js

```
    $("#overflowdiv").scroll(function () {
        console.debug("scroll activado!");
        console.debug($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() + " " + $(this)[0].scrollHeight);

        if( $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            loadProducts();
        }
    });
```

This is working fine for me.